# com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: Error converting characters into server's character set. Some character(s) could not be converted

Tags: spring-boot, sybase

I was trying to save chinese characters into the sybase database. the encoding of my sybase databse is big5hk. However, the error occured.  Error converting characters into server's character set. Some character(s) could not be converted.

following is my code to setup the datasource.

```
HikariDataSource dataSource = (HikariDataSource) DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .driverClassName("com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver").url(url).username(username).password(password)
            .build();
dataSource.setConnectionTestQuery("select 1");
dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(maximumPoolSize);
dataSource.setMaxLifetime(30000);
dataSource.setConnectionInitSql("set char_convert off");
dataSource.setConnectionTimeout(30000);
dataSource.setValidationTimeout(30000);
dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("characterEncoding","big5hk");
return dataSource;
```